# Codeigniter how to set form action url using form_open helper function

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter with Bootstrap. This is my view code:

```
<?php echo form_open('con_login/loginUser'); ?>
    <div class="bs-example">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" value="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="login" value="login">Sign in</button>
    </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

The code for the called function which is in the controller is:

```
public function loginUser() {
    $username = $this->mod_login->getUsername();

    $inUser = $this->input->post('username');
    $inPass = $this->input->post('password');

    if (in_array($inUser, $username)) {
        $password = $this->mod_login->getPassword($inUser);
        if ($password === $inPass) {
            $this->load->view('Alt_home');
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error

> The requested URL /SEP/con_login/loginUser was not found on this server.

Why is this? Is there anything to do with Routing?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass complete url to the form_open function like this

```
<form action='http://localhost/folder/controller/method'>
```

There are two method to do this

**1: Using base_url()**

Step 1: Open the config.php file under application\config folder

step 2: Set the value of `$config['base_url']`  to your website path

```
  $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/foldername/index.php";
```

**How to use**

Load the url helper in controller

```
 $this->load->helper('url);
```

Now in the view file you can use like this

```
  echo form_open(base_url()."/controllername/mehod");
```

**2: Manually**

```
   form_open("http://localhost/foldername/index.php/controller/method");
```

Comment: I mean can't you even call a controller function from form_open(functionName)? But I have seen such code. Is this adding a helper is a must?

Comment: form_open is a helper function, Not class. See here http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: Let me know what do you want to achieve by calling the controller function from view ?

Comment: I need to authenticate a user by checking the username and password which was being input from the form_open()

Comment: see in http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/helpers/form_helper.html too you can call a controller function. Isn't it? or have I messed everything up

Comment: oh! you have misunderstood the documentation. You will need to pass a controller/method name to the form_open it will print the line like this <form action='controller/method'> and on the controller file you will write code where you will receive the input by GET/POST

Comment: That's exactly what I need. So form_open(controller/method) equals <form action='controller/method'> right? I am using the data from POST in the controller method. So why this URL not found error?

Comment: if you removed index.php using .htaccess than link to your controller/method should look like this /SEP/con_login/loginUser and if index.php is not removed than it should be /SEP/index.php/con_login/loginUser. form_open automatically set this for your according to your setting so kindly check the source of your document and see particular form and its action, is it in correct form ? it should look like /SEP/con_login/loginUser as it won't work.

Comment: What is 'SEP' here  ? foldername ?

Comment: Assuming you didn't set the base url to localhost/SEP then your form open should be /SEP/con_login/loginUser which will evaluate to localhost/SEP/con_login/loginUser

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass complete url to the form_open function like this

```
<form action='http://localhost/folder/controller/method'>
```

There are two method to do this

#### 1: Using `base_url()`

Step 1: Open the config.php file under application\config folder

step 2: Set the value of $config['base_url'] to your website path

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/foldername/index.php";
```

How to use

Load the url helper in controller

```
$this->load->helper('url);
```

Now in the view file you can use like this

```
 echo form_open(base_url()."/controllername/mehod");
```

#### 2: Manually

```
form_open("http://localhost/foldername/index.php/controller/method");
```

Answer (score 0):

did you load helper (url,form) in your controller
if not
then u should make a load function in your controller
just like this

```
public function load(){  
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
}
```

and use this in function

```
    public function loginUser() {
    $this->load();
    $username = $this->mod_login->getUsername();

    $inUser = $this->input->post('username');
    $inPass = $this->input->post('password');

    if (in_array($inUser, $username)) {
        $password = $this->mod_login->getPassword($inUser);
        if ($password === $inPass) {
            $this->load->view('Alt_home');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use like this, Its works for me.. lets see if it is works for you or not.
>   If you don't want attributes remove from second argument of form_open() function.

```
<?php $attributes = array('class' => 'myformclass', 'id' => 'myformid','name' => 'myformname');
            echo form_open(base_url("con_login/loginUser"),$attributes);?>
```

> HTML HERE

```
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

> Thank You